# Create model instance out of Form and add it to other instance

Tags: python, django

In my models.py I have model called `Bus`. It contains multiple fields, including the field `file` below:

```
class Bus(models.Model):
    file = models.OneToOneField('File', on_delete=models.PROTECT, editable=False)
```

The `File` model consists of:

```
class File(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(
        upload_to=get_filepath,
        max_length=45,
        validators=[
            FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['pdf', 'jpg', 'png']),
            file_size,
        ]
    )
    original_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    extension = models.CharField(max_length=3)
```

When you want to create a new `Bus` I need of course a form. That's defined in my forms.py:

```
class BusForm(forms.ModelForm):
    upload = forms.FileField(max_length=45, required=False,
                            validators=[
                                FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['pdf', 'jpg', 'png']),
                                file_size,
                            ],)
```

**My problem:**

In the `save()` method of `BusForm` I have to create a `File` instance and add it to the `Bus` instance (`file` field).

For multiple hours I tried to achieve that. However, I don't get it. If someone could try to help me how the `save()` method has to look like, that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `save` method like this

```
def save(self, commit=False):
    # This will create bus_instance but not save in database
    bus_instance = super(self, BusForm).save(commit=False) 

    # create file instance
    file_instance = File.objects.create() # add the required parameters

    # Assign file_instance to file attribute of bus_instance
    bus_instance.file = file_instance

    # Save to database only if user calling save method wants to save in database
    if commit:
        bus_instance.save()

    return bus_instance
```